# Cannot connect to VPN ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I'm using hide.me I followed the tutorial, but I cannot connect to the vpn.

It shows up in the menu, but I cannot select it, it just does nothing. I think it should be common sense to allow for an option to connect to the VPN as soon as i create a connection. I've been messing with this all day to no avail.

[image]

I cannot select any of those connections selecting them does nothing, and my VPN is still not connected.

Comment: Which VPN type are you using? OpenVPN, PPTP, L2TP etc?

Comment: Have you tried editing your ethernet connection (wired network) in the Network Connections window and checking "Automatically connect to a VPN" in the edit window that opens?

Comment: @smile4ever yes i have done this

Comment: @krt im not sure but i have selected the import a saved vpn configuration